# Prove properties of lists

Tags: coq

My aim is to prove that certain properties of generated lists hold.
For instance, a generator function produces a list of 1s, the length of the list is given as an argument; I'd like to prove that the length of the list is what the argument specifies. This is what I have so far:

```
Require Import List.

Fixpoint list_gen lng acc :=
match lng with
0 => acc
| S lng_1 => list_gen (lng_1) (1::acc)
end.

Lemma lm0 : length(list_gen 0 nil) = 0.
intuition.
Qed.

Lemma lm1 : forall lng:nat, length(list_gen lng nil) = lng.
induction lng.
apply lm0.
```

Now after applying lm0 the induction step is left:

```
1 subgoal
lng : nat
IHlng : length (list_gen lng nil) = lng
______________________________________(1/1)
length (list_gen (S lng) nil) = S lng
```

I was hoping that the proof of this step would be deduced from the code of list_gen but it's most likely a mistaken concept. How can this subgoal be proved?

Comment: I would guess probably you need to generalize what you're proving to handle cases where the `acc` argument is not `nil`: `forall (lng:nat) (acc:list nat), length (list_gen lng acc) = lng + length acc.`  (And then `simpl` should be very helpful in proving the inductive step...)

Comment: You might want to check [Exercises on Generalizing the Induction Hypothesis](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrw12/InductionExercises.html) by James Wilcox

Comment: Anton, the article seems very promising first but finally the only subject it teaches is that intermediate lemmas should be applied in the more intricate induction proofs. How to construct these lemmas is left open by the author.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly You probably need some experience to come up directly with these lemmas, but the conclusion of the article is that when there is an accumulator, you almost surely need to prove a more general result holding for any accumulator (as suggested by @Daniel in a comment above). Actually, you can also get this idea by trying the direct proof and understanding why you are blocked. Here, if you use `simpl`, it is clear that you need an induction hypothesis where `acc` is not `nil`, and thus you can have the intuition of the generalized version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with Daniel's approach, however a bit more general one is to write out a spec of `list_gen`, e.g. using *non-tail-recursive* `repeat` function:

```
Require Import List Arith.
Import ListNotations.

Lemma list_gen_spec : forall lng acc, list_gen lng acc = repeat 1 lng ++ acc.
Proof.
  induction lng as [| lng IH]; intros xs; simpl; trivial.
  rewrite IH.
  now rewrite app_cons_middle, repeat_singleton, repeat_app, Nat.add_comm.
Qed.
```

where I had to add a bunch of lemmas about `repeat`'s interaction with some standard list functions.

```
Lemma repeat_singleton {A} (x : A) :
  [x] = repeat x 1.
Admitted.

Lemma repeat_app {A} (x : A) n m :
  repeat x n ++ repeat x m = repeat x (n + m).
Admitted.

Lemma app_cons {A} (x : A) xs :
  x :: xs = [x] ++ xs.
Admitted.  (* this is a convenience lemma for the next one *)

Lemma app_cons_middle {A} (y : A) xs ys :
  xs ++ y :: ys = (xs ++ [y]) ++ ys.
Admitted.
```

I'll leave the proofs of these lemmas as an exercise.

After proving the spec, your lemma could be proved with a few rewrites.

```
Lemma lm1 lng : length(list_gen lng nil) = lng.
Proof.
  now rewrite list_gen_spec, app_nil_r, repeat_length.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you, Anton. A most educative answer for me.

Comment: Anton, what is the relation of list_gen_spec with list_gen? I notice that in the specification the essence of the function is expressed, that is concatenating 1s; in this case what's the role of list_gen? Another issue is that in the case of a more complicated pattern generator,  a specification like that couldn't be formed.

Comment: (1) You seem to get everything right about `list_gen_spec` -- it allows you to connect a (potentially) faster tail-recursive implementation (`list_gen`) with another more obvious (imho) and *easier to reason about* implementation (based on `repeat` and `++` functions). (2) I agree with you that it's not always possible to give a clean and simple spec, but one should strive for it and when it's possible one should use it for their advantage.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the repeat_singleton lemma. Could you briefly explain what it states, please? Thank you.

Comment: It is essentially a special case of the spec for `repeat` when the counter is 1. I use it to turn `repeat 1 lng ++ [1]` into  `(repeat 1 lng ++ repeat 1 1)`, so that I could transform the latter into `repeat 1 (lng + 1)` using `repeat_app`. You can change `now rewrite app_cons_middle, repeat_singleton, repeat_app, Nat.add_comm.` into a sequence of rewrites: `rewrite app_cons_middle. rewrite repeat_singleton. rewrite repeat_app. ...` and check what is going on stepping through it interactively.

Comment: Anton, I've more complex pattern generators than the simple one in my question. How do I go about proving properties of the lists generated by them, assuming the essence of the generating functions can not be extracted into specifications like the one in your answer?

Comment: Sometimes it's extremely hard to come up with a full spec. In this case one can at least prove some important properties of the code at hand. It's hard to say more without looking at your special case... If you could you post a snippet somewhere (and a bit of informal explanation), then I could try to help with that.